# MyLocationOverlay: getMyLocation returning null

Tags: android, google-maps, location

I have a mapview page that displays the current location in the map.

I am using MyLocationOverlay for the purpose. The code for that goes as follows:

```
myLocationOverlay = new MyLocationOverlay(this, mapView);
myLocationOverlay.enableCompass();
myLocationOverlay.enableMyLocation();

myLocationOverlay.runOnFirstFix(new Runnable() {
public void run() {
 geopoint = myLocationOverlay.getMyLocation();
 ItemizedOverlay itemizedoverlay = new ItemizedOverlay(drawable);
 try{
  overlayitem = new OverlayItem(geopoint, "", "");
 }
 catch(Exception e){
  e.printStackTrace();
 }
 itemizedoverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem);
 mapOverlays.add(itemizedoverlay);
 mapController.animateTo(geoPoint);

 }
});
```

The above code works and gets the current location through gps and sets a marker at that point.

But the code inside try block is the issue.
I am getting null value inside geopoint.

Actually I have to get that point and do some calculations with distance and all. For that I have to get the correct value inside that geopoint.

Can anyone please tell the solution for this?

Comment: Have you added location permissions to manifest?

Answer (score 1):

I've been working on the same problem for a day now and here's what I've discovered. For some reason this works

```
LocationManager lm;
GeoPoint gp;        

lm = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
Location lastKnownLoc = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

if (lastKnownLoc != null){
  int longTemp = (int)(lastKnownLoc.getLongitude()* 1000000);
  int latTemp = (int)(lastKnownLoc.getLatitude() * 1000000);
  gp =  new GeoPoint(latTemp, longTemp);
}
```

and this doesn't

```
gp = myLocOverlay.getMyLocation();
```

Comment: Well, that avoids null pointer exception but doesn't fixes the problem. At least not with the information you are putting here.

Answer (score 0):

Tracking current location can be done by using MyLocationOverlay class and through LocationManager. Using MyLocationOverlay, the code below works..

```
MyLocationOverlay myLocationOverlay;
MapView mapView;
MapController mapcontroller;
OverlayItem overlayitem;
List<Overlay> mapoverlays;
GeoPoint geopoint;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.currentlocation);

  mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.map);

  mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
  mapView.setSatellite(false);
  mapView.setStreetView(true);
  mapView.setTraffic(true);

  mapcontroller = mapView.getController();
  mapoverlays = mapView.getOverlays();
  drawable = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_map_red);
  mapView.invalidate();

  getCurrentLocation();             
}

public void getCurrentLocation(){  

   myLocationOverlay = new MyLocationOverlay(this, mapView);
   myLocationOverlay.enableCompass();
   myLocationOverlay.enableMyLocation();
   myLocationOverlay.runOnFirstFix(new Runnable() {

     public void run() {

   ItemizedOverlay itemizedoverlay = new ItemizedOverlay(drawable);

   try {
    latitude = myLocationOverlay.getMyLocation().getLatitudeE6();
    longitude = myLocationOverlay.getMyLocation().getLongitudeE6();
            geopoint = new GeoPoint((int) (latitude), (int) (longitude));
    overlayitem = new OverlayItem(geopoint, "", "");
    itemizedoverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem);
    mapoverlays.add(itemizedoverlay);
    mapcontroller.animateTo(geopoint);
    mapcontroller.setZoom(16);
   } 
   catch (Exception e) {}
    }           
  });       
}
```

Comment: Are you sure this works? First of all when you enableLocation() the current location should be drawn all by itself, correct? So why are you creating a drawable and drawing it to the first received location? Another thing: put .enableMyLocation() into onResume() and put .disableMyLocation() into onPause() to avoid keeping GPS on forever!

Comment: Ah i think i just saw what you did there. This seems rather complicated to ise the MyLocationOverlay to get a one-time-location. Use LocationManager.getLastKnownLocation() instead. And if you want to continue showing the updated location, call mapoverlays.add(myLocationOverlay) instead of drawing anything yourself.

Answer (score 0):

If you override:

```
onLocationChanged();
```

Remember to call:

```
super.onLocationChanged();
```

after or before your own code. This appears to ensure that the variable

```
getMyLocation()
```

returns is not null.

Comment: I have that as my first call in my custom onLocationChanged and getMyLocation() is still returning null for me.

Answer (score 0):

The friend upstairs made me rise that try override nothing, neither draw nor drawMyLocation.
Just like this:

```
MyLocationOverlay myLocationOverlay = new SelfLocationOverlay(this, mapView);
myLocationOverlay.enableMyLocation();
myLocationOverlay.disableCompass();
mapView.getOverlays().add(myLocationOverlay);
```